# Amazon RDS for Oracle Offsite Backup

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

Am considering Amazon RDS to host our Oracle database. Ideally, I'd like to have my daily backup and as many of the transaction logs as possible since copied to an external location in case of Amazon failure. Although they've automated the backup/restore process, I can't rely totally on that and don't see a way to create an offsite backup of my data. The closest thing I can find is in their announcement for cross-region snapshot copies:

"Once a DB Snapshot is copied to a specific AWS Region, any subsequent copy operations of the DB Snapshots of the same DB Instance to that Region will only transfer the data that has changed since the last copy. Thus the subsequent copy operations transfer fewer amounts of data and complete faster."

Seems to imply that I could copy a snapshot multiple times a day, obviously a hack. Anyone have a solution for this?